# xword not accepting keyboard letters

Tags: games, 15.04

Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, xword crossword puzzle game is not accepting letters from a hardware keyboard nor onscreen keyboard. Keyboard shortcuts are working to advance to the next letter, word, etc. it just won't accept any letters. Starting via terminal shows no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some searching for the answer I found the cause. Num Lock was on, turning it off solved the problem. Strange that it only affects the game and nothing else.